# Проверка заполненности input полей с изменением событий

Tags: jquery, form, input

Добрый день!
Имеется задача:
форма с полями input, которые при смене фокуса выдают красный крестик в конце поля.
Но если пользователь заполнил поле (независимо после вывода красного крестика либо без вывода) то в конце поля появляется зеленая галочка.
Как это реализовать посредством jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Подписываемся на [`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/), там проверяем на заполненность и докидываем нужный класс.

```js
$('input').change(function() {
  let el = $(this).parent();
  if ($(this).val()) {
    el.addClass('success');
    el.removeClass('error');
  } else {
    el.addClass('error');
    el.removeClass('success');
  }
});
```

```css
span {
  position: relative;
}

.success:after,
.error:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 4px;
  color: green;
  content: '\2713';
}

.success:after {
  color: green;
  content: '\2713';
}

.error:after {
  color: red;
  top: -2px;
  content: '\2717';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>
<input type="text" />
</span>
```